# machine learning accuracy report error message

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a small sample of 200 observations. The following is the code that I use.

```
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
evaluate_nn(y_test, y_test_pred.round(), train=False)
```

I have very high accuracy. See the following output.

```
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
Test Result:
================================================
Accuracy Score: 92.86%
_______________________________________________
CLASSIFICATION REPORT:
           0.0   1.0  accuracy  macro avg  weighted avg
precision 0.00  0.93      0.93       0.46          0.86
recall    0.00  1.00      0.93       0.50          0.93
f1-score  0.00  0.96      0.93       0.48          0.89
support   7.00 91.00      0.93      98.00         98.00
_______________________________________________
Confusion Matrix: 
 [[ 0  7]
 [ 0 91]]
```

However, I got the following warning.

> C:\Users\gaowe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics_classification.py:1318: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
> _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))

How can I address this issue?

Comment: "very high accuracy" - the confusion matrix seems terrible, though: the model essentially always outputs `1`. Is this expected?

Comment: @ForceBru: why do you think the confusion matrix is terrible? Could you please explain? I don't expect any particular accuracy level. Thanks for editing my question text. It looks so much nicer and readable.

Comment: Well, the confusion matrix shows that the model predicts one (bottom-right corner) all the time. Moreover, the dataset mostly contains ones (again, since the highest number in the matrix is in the bottom-left corner which corresponds to `(1,1)`), so it's imbalanced. Since the model _never_ predicted zero (the first column is empty), some metrics (like precision and F-score the warning message is talking about) can't be computed.

Comment: And the warning tells you exactly that, i.e. that some class (here `0`) was never predicted by the model, hence precision & recall cannot be computed. Accuracy is essentially meaningless in imbalanced data. But this is not a *programming* issue, please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info